# Redirect https://alias to https://web without warning

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, domain-aliasing

I need all requests to go to https://example.com which I have SSL cert for.
My alias example.ch redirect to the example.com by

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ch$ [OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ch$
     RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not work if I put https://example.ch. Chrome drops the warning message (Your connection is not private). Is there a way to overcome this warning and smoothly redirect?

Ive tried to add

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: _Is there a way to overcome this warning and smoothly redirect?_ yes. Also get a valid cert for `example.ch`. That is your **ONLY** option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP without a certificate (Apache VirtualHosts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143210/how-to-redirect-https-requests-to-http-without-a-certificate-apache-virtualhost)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what would be the best cert for such purpose (just redirecting)?