# NGINX redirect all https traffic to http

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

In nginx, is it possible to redirect all https requests to http? I know that I can do a rewrite rule but would it be possible to do this without having to create certificates/private keys on the nginx servers for port 443?

I need this for a web server that will only host static content on http...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible.  The TLS communication layer is set-up before any website data is sent from the client, so without the certificate, you would get the "website insecure warning from the browser".  You can get fairly cheap SSL certificates.  I would recommend that you just host everything on HTTPS and can improve brand trust.  Good Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143210/how-to-redirect-https-requests-to-http-without-a-certificate-apache-virtualhost

Answer (score 0):

For the browser to receive the redirect, TLS connection should already have been made, so this is not possible - you should set up valid certificates (no need for premium extended validation, free ones from letsencrypt are enough).

Also if previously there was a strict-transport-security header (HSTS) you probably want to set it to `max-age=0` while redirecting, otherwise browsers will keep trying https