# How to 301 redirect HTTP to HTTPS properly with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301

My goal is to 301 all variants of my domain name to forever be https://*.com via htaccess. Also, is this is the best way to go about accomplishing it?

E.g., `http://`, `http://www`. and `https://www`. >> `https://`

I would like for all of its files and/or subdirectories to be https:// as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply just do this.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before trying these new rules. Let me know how this works out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply --- however, I would like http, http www AND https www to all 301 to simply https:// --- of course its subdirectories and files to land https:// as well - please assist

Comment: Did it work out for you? If so please accept the answer by checking the checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: Did you test it? It does exactly that. You can test it here. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: when typing in https www example it does not 301 to https example ... it remains https www

Comment: Are you getting a certificate warning?

Comment: http and http www go to https properly. however, https www does not to go to https properly. Regarding cert warning, yes --- i do not have a cert installed yet.

Comment: That is your problem. _The rule works fine_. You **must** have a valid certificate for this to work. The SSL handshake connect happens before the redirect. You can read more on my other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32143677/330987. When you install a valid cert it will work.